# How to handle stale element exception reference while looping through dropdown

Tags: automated-testing

My requirement is actually to click on the option in the dropdown one by one and then click search i.e. I will first select the first option then search , then again go back to the second option and click search. This is to be continued till the last option

Comment: I've voted to close this as it looks like a duplicate of your other question (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/34377/9208). If you can edit your question enough for it to be different, then it might be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

In if condition, you have already written click() again outside of loop again why we need click and no need to use List for single search button, you can give direct search xpath for it, if it has to continue till last open, please remove break in if condition.

Comment: There are three buttons on the same page with same xpaths, so using  list to store them and then get it by index, click is for selecting that option from the dropdown, and other click is to search

Comment: removing break also didnt help

Comment: keep search button click withing for loop, otherwise ur search button gets selected only one item after completing complete for loop iteration.

Comment: I am getting StaleElementReferenceException for the code now

Answer (score 0):

The problem with StaleElementReferenceException is usually that you look up elements on a page, hold them in a variable and then do some interaction that causes the page to change or reload.
It seems you are doing exactly this: the `list` variable is initialized first, then you loop through it and then you click a search button multiple times, which probably updates the page. This makes the `list` variable invalid and will cause the exception if you try to interact with any of it's elements.

What might work in this case is if you do the following:

- Hold a variable of the amount of items in the list (currently `a`, it's recommended to have more descriptive variable names)
- Loop through all values between 0 (inclusive) and `a` with index `i`.
- Within each iteration, initialize `list` again and take element `i`
- Proceed to do the same as what you are currently already doing inside the loop with element `e`

Comment: needed some help with this - "Within each iteration, initialize list again and take element i", with ref to my code